# Why array indexing not showing commutative behavior in this program?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, compiler-errors

I know that array indexing is commutative in both C & C++, so a[i] is same as i[a] and it would have same effect as i[a] and both are valid. But recently I wrote a following program that fails to compile when I use i[intob] instead of intob[i].

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using std::cout;
template<class T>class atype
{
    T* a;
    int size;
    public:
        atype(int n)
        {
            size=n;
            a=new T[size];
            for(auto i=0;i<size;i++)
                a[i]=i;
        }
        ~atype()
        {
            delete[] a;
        }
        T& operator[](int i);
};
template<class T> T& atype<T>::operator[](int i)
{
    if(i<0 || i>size)
    {
        cout<<"\nIndex value of ";
        cout<<i<<" is out of bounds.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    return a[i];   // i[a] also works fine here.
}
int main()
{
    int i,n;
    cout<<"Enter value of n: ";
    std::cin>>n;
    atype<int> intob{n};
    atype<long int> longintob{n};
    cout<<"Integer array: ";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        intob[i]=i; 
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<i[intob]<<' ';    // oops compiler error why???
    cout<<'\n';

    cout<<"long integer array: ";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        longintob[i]=i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<longintob[i]<<' ';
    longintob[15]=123;
}
```

I am getting following compiler error.

**[Error] no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'int' and 'atype')**

But If I write i[a] in overloaded [] operator function then it works fine. Why?

Is there any solution exist to access array elements using i[intob]?

Tell me If I am wrong somewhere & understanding something incorrectly.

Comment: `atype` violates the rule of three.

Comment: You have a destructor, but no copy constructor and no copy assignment operator.

Comment: If you write `atype<int> a(1), b(1); a = b;` you have a memory leak and a double free.

Comment: @fredoverflow: But I am not performing any assignments or copy. Then why do I need to write assignment operator & copy constructor? What if I really don't need assignments or copy.

Comment: Then you should declare the copy constructor and the assignment operator private and leave them unimplemented. Or `= delete` them, if you have a C++11 compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indexing operator itself is not commutative.

It helps if you understand that for an array (or pointer) `a` and an index `i` then `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a + i)`. The commutative bit comes from that addition, because `*(a + i)` is equal to `*(i + a)` which leads to `i[a]` being valid.

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler checks the type, and in c++ there is a thing called *operator overloading* which means i could write my own operators for my own types:

```
typedef int stupidInt;

intoperator+(int l, stupidInt r){
  return l-r;
}

int operator+(stupidInt l, int r){
  return l+r;
}
stupidInt a = 3;
int b = 7;

a + b == 10; 
b + a == 4;
```

this also goes for operator[](typea, typeb);

and somewhere there is probably a definition `operator[](atype, int)` . (Maybe this is hardcoded in the compiler) 
But not the other way around.

There is also not really a reason why you would need to put this the other way around. But you could probably define

```
int operator[](int i, atype a){
  return a[i];
}
```

This should make the operator also work in reverse.